# Fatal Exception: NSRangeException NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Here is my code :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *resultString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    BOOL isPressedBackspaceAfterSingleSpaceSymbol = [string isEqualToString:@""] && [resultString isEqualToString:@""] && range.location == 0 && range.length == 1;
    if (isPressedBackspaceAfterSingleSpaceSymbol) {
        if (textField == self.txt1 ) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.txt1 resignFirstResponder];
            });
        } else if (textField == self.txt2 ) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.txt1 becomeFirstResponder];
            });
        } else if (textField ==  self.txt3 ) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
            });
        } else if (textField ==  self.txt4) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.txt3 becomeFirstResponder];
            });
        }
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (textField == self.txt1 ) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.txt1.text = string;
                    [self.txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
                });
                if (self.txt1.text.length == 1) {
                    [self.txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
                }
            } else if (textField == self.txt2 ) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.txt2.text = string;
                    [self.txt3 becomeFirstResponder];
                });
                if (self.txt2.text.length == 1) {
                    [self.txt3 becomeFirstResponder];
                }
            } else if (textField ==  self.txt3 ) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.txt3.text = string;
                    [self.txt4 becomeFirstResponder];
                });
                if (self.txt3.text.length == 1) {
                    [self.txt4 becomeFirstResponder];
                }
            } else if (textField ==  self.txt4) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.txt4.text = string;
                    [self.txt4 resignFirstResponder];
                });
                if (self.txt4.text.length == 1) {
                    [self.txt4 resignFirstResponder];
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am facing **out of bounds** error. i don't know how.

crash showing line number 186 which is `self.txt1.text = string;`

**Note:-** This is my otp view controller. i have 4 textfields for 4 digit otp. i am allow to user to input only numbers in textfields. one number in one textfield.

Thank you.

Comment: Too many nested dispatched blocks, I suggest you to bring all code under single dispatch queue and remove if really not required

Comment: okay i will. but it will solve my crash ?

Comment: May be or May be not. because what I am seeing is as soon as you dispatched another thread string might be changed by current thread so you may get wrong string. You should give a try

Comment: okay i will try.

Comment: Hi @NiravKotecha just curious, why do you need to call `dispatch_async` to `main queue` while the method `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` should be on main thread right? or actually that method is invoked in a background thread?